# Ajax Jquery Success Message on a Label

Tags: jquery

How can I change the alert into a Label?

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: pageUrl + '/ProcessADRequest',
                data: '{SSNID: "' + $("[id$='_empLast4Txt']").val() + '", DOB: "' +    $("[id$='_empDobTxt']").val() + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) { alert(response.d); },
                failure: function (response) { alert(response.d); }

            });
```

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Instead of rendering the response in a alert box, you want to add a label to the page?

Comment: Yes, I want to render the result in a Label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you just want to render it in a label and assuming you want it appended to the body of the document, then here you go

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + '/ProcessADRequest',
        data: '{SSNID: "' + $("[id$='_empLast4Txt']").val() + '", DOB: "' +    $("[id$='_empDobTxt']").val() + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) { $('body').append("<label>" +response.d + "</label>"); },
        failure: function (response) { alert(response.d); }

      });
```

Comment: I'm using <asp:ValidationSummary> to validate my form. When I click on Submit, it renders the response to the Label even if there are any validation errors. I want it to render the response only after the form is submitted. How can I accomplish this?